# Can I use `If` in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you even put an if statement in a select like this or must you use Case statements for what I'm trying to do here?  I get syntax errors currently:

```
Select 
    field1,
    field2,
    If( @CurrentDate = @lastDate and @CurrentWeek = @lastWeek) 
              select @CurrentWeek,
    .... rest of select statement
```

Comment: nopes u cant use if in select statement

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `CASE`. Note however, that you can use CASE as both a `SWITCH` and as a `IF ... THEN ... ELSEIF ... ELSE`, so you have loads of flexibility.

For example:

```
DECLARE @flag INT
SET @flag = 1

-- Switch
SELECT CASE @flag WHEN 1 THEN 'Condition True' 
                  WHEN 0 THEN 'Condition FALSE' 
                  ELSE 'Condition Invalid' 
       END

-- If / elseif / else
SELECT CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
                 THEN 'Condition True' 
            WHEN @flag = 0 AND @@SERVERNAME = 'TotallyUnrelatedToFlag' 
                 THEN 'Condition FALSE' 
            ELSE 'Condition Invalid' 
       END
```

In your example, it seems that you need something along the lines of

```
Select 
    field1,
    field2,
    CASE WHEN (@CurrentDate = @lastDate and @CurrentWeek = @lastWeek) 
         THEN @CurrentWeek
         ELSE NULL
    END As field3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a `CASE` statement

```
Select 
    field1,
    field2,
    case when @CurrentDate = @lastDate and @CurrentWeek = @lastWeek
         then @CurrentWeek else '' end
    .... rest of select statement
```

If you want to use an `IF` statement, then you will want to use something like this:

```
If (@CurrentDate = @lastDate and @CurrentWeek = @lastWeek)
  begin
    -- place the one select statement here
    select ...from
  end
else
  begin
     -- place the alternate select here
     select... from
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a case statement instead. The [IF...ELSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182717%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) construct in TSQL can be used to conditionally execute a SQL statement. It cannot be used *within* a SQL statement. Please read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182717%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which makes this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    field1,
    field2,
    CASE WHEN @CurrentDate = @lastDate and @CurrentWeek = @lastWeek THEN @CurrentWeek ELSE '' END as Week,
```